# Python - Multiple errors

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a little side project yet having multiple issues.
I'm reading a file within the folder where the project is that holds data for 10 users.

Right now, I'm getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1668, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 133, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 120, in main
    print("Pour la personne" , id_usager , ", nous recommandons l'ami" , recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite))
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 91, in recommander
    usager_matrice = matrice_similarite.index(id_usager)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

As for the code itself... It's pretty big.

```
def ouvrir_fichier(nomFichier):
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring

    """
    try:
        fp = open(nomFichier, 'r')
        return fp
    except:
        return print("Le fichier n'existe pas. Veuillez réessayer.")

def lire_fichier(fp):
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring"""
    # Lis n et initialise une liste vide --
    #    où il y a une liste vide pour chaque usager du réseau
    #    ensuite lis le reste du fichier et ajouter l'information à reseau

    liste1 = fp.readlines()
    n = int(liste1[0])
    liste2 = liste1[1:]

    reseau = [[] for i in range(n)]
    for i in liste2:
        i = i.replace("\n", "")
        data = i.split(" ")
        valeur1 = int(data[0])
        valeur2 = int(data[1])
        reseau[valeur1].append(valeur2)
        reseau[valeur2].append(valeur1)
    fp.close()
    return reseau

def trouver_nombre_elements_communs_entre_listes(liste1, liste2):
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring"""
    compteur_amis_commun = 0
    for element in liste1:
        if element in liste2:
            compteur_amis_commun = compteur_amis_commun + 1
    return compteur_amis_commun


def initialiser_matrice(n):
    """
    Crée une matrice nxn, initialisée avec des zéros et retourne la matrice.
    Args:
        n (int): dimension de la matrice nxn
    Returns:
        matrice (list): matrice initialisée

    """
    matrice = []
    for ligne in range(n):  # pour chacune des lignes dans n
        matrice.append([])  # créer une ligne (liste) et l'initialiser à 0
        for colonne in range(n):
            matrice[ligne].append(0)  # ajouter un 0 pour chaque n colonne
    return matrice


def calculer_scores_similarite(reseau):
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring"""
    n = len(reseau)
    matrice_similarite = initialiser_matrice(n)
    liste1 = []
    liste2 = []
    compteur_liste1 = 0
    compteur_liste2 = 0

    for element_liste1 in reseau:
        liste1 = element_liste1
        for element_liste2 in reseau:
            liste2 = element_liste2
            compteur_amis_commun = trouver_nombre_elements_communs_entre_listes(liste1, liste2)
            matrice_similarite[compteur_liste1][compteur_liste2] = compteur_amis_commun
            compteur_liste2 = compteur_liste2 + 1
        compteur_liste1 = compteur_liste1 + 1
        compteur_liste2 = 0

    return matrice_similarite


def recommander(id_usager,reseau,matrice_similarite):
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring"""

    usager_matrice = matrice_similarite.index(id_usager)
    ami_recommande = matrice_similarite.index(max(usager_matrice))
    max_value = max(matrice_similarite.index(usager_matrice))

    if ami_recommande == id_usager:
        max_value = max_value - 1

    ami_recommande = matrice_similarite.index(max_value)

    while True:
        if ami_recommande == reseau.index(ami_recommande):
            ami_recommande = reseau.index(max_value, ami_recommande + 1)
            return True

    return ami_recommande

def main():

    nomFichier = input("Nom du fichier contenant le réseau: ")
    reseau = lire_fichier(ouvrir_fichier(nomFichier))
    n = len(reseau)
    matrice_similarite = calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)
    while True:

        while True:

            id_usager = int(input("Entrer l'ID de l'usager pour lequel vous voulez une recommandation (entre 0 et {}):".format(n)))
            if 0 <= id_usager and id_usager < n:
                calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)
                print("Pour la personne" , id_usager , ", nous recommandons l'ami" , recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite))
                continue
            else:
                print("Erreur: l'usager doit être un nombre entier entre ", 0, "et", n - 1, "inclusivement.\n")

        autreRecommandation = input("Voulez-vous une autre recommandation (oui/non)?")
        if autreRecommandation.lower() == "oui":
            return True
        else:
            print("Merci d'avoir utiliser le programme de recommandation d'amis.")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Most of the content seems to be working fine until I get to part where I need to recommend a user identification. I'll try to work on the doc string as well in the meantime but I could totally use a little bit of help as to debug this. I tested most of the code on another .py project until I hit the function "recommander"

Thanks

First Edit :

I did forget to apply the Return. I changed it and it is now in the def. Now however... I seem to be having this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1668, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 132, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 119, in main
    print("Pour la personne" , id_usager , ", nous recommandons l'ami" , recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite))
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 89, in recommander
    usager_matrice = matrice_similarite.index(id_usager)
ValueError: 0 is not in list
```

Comment: It seems like the problem is that `calculer_scores_similarite` isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback has the answer:

```
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 91, in recommander
    usager_matrice = matrice_similarite.index(id_usager)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

This simply means that `matrice_similarite` is `None`.
Now when you read the traceback to the top, you see that the failing call to `recommander` is in `main`, with the line:

```
print(
    "Pour la personne",
    id_usager,
    ", nous recommandons l'ami",
    recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite))
```

At this point, `matrice_similarite` has been defined as follows:

```
matrice_similarite = calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)
```

And as one would expect, `calculer_scores_similarite` returns nothing, hence `None`.
Reading the definition of this function, I guess you simply forgot to return the matrix you're computing, so adding the following should do:

```
return matrice_similarite
```

Comment: I've got a new error. Yet it is too long for me to post it in there.
  File TP2.py", line 132, in <module>main()File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 119, in main print("Pour la personne" , id_usager , ", nous recommandons l'ami" , recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite))
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 89, in recommander usager_matrice = matrice_similarite.index(id_usager)
ValueError: 0 is not in list

Comment: @Nore You should open a new question. If you do so, gimme the link and I'll try to help you.

Comment: I edited the post instead that way I don't overflow with new posts and bug people over nothing.

Comment: @Nore That's not really the point. On the contrary, editing your post will prevent users from seeing every issue. The questions should be atomic as possible.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I can post it, I will. There's a 90 minutes I've got to respect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061132/valueerror-0-is-not-in-list-when-running-this-code?noredirect=1#comment85127695_49061132

Answer (score 0):

You have small error in your code.

On line 102 you call:
`matrice_similarite = calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)`

and function `calculer_scores_similarite` doesn't have return value

you need to add in that function `return matrice_similarite` as last line of function.

Comment: Thank you. That did work the problem out. I'm having another issue due to the change however which is why I edited the post.