# ValueError: 0 is not in list when running this code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a little side project yet having multiple issues. I'm reading a file within the folder where the project is that holds data for 10 users.

As for the code itself...it's pretty big.

```
def ouvrir_fichier(nomFichier):
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring

    """
    try:
        fp = open(nomFichier, 'r')
        return fp
    except:
        return print("Le fichier n'existe pas. Veuillez réessayer.")

def lire_fichier(fp):
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring"""
    # Lis n et initialise une liste vide --
    #    où il y a une liste vide pour chaque usager du réseau
    #    ensuite lis le reste du fichier et ajouter l'information à reseau

    liste1 = fp.readlines()
    n = int(liste1[0])
    liste2 = liste1[1:]

    reseau = [[] for i in range(n)]
    for i in liste2:
        i = i.replace("\n", "")
        data = i.split(" ")
        valeur1 = int(data[0])
        valeur2 = int(data[1])
        reseau[valeur1].append(valeur2)
        reseau[valeur2].append(valeur1)
    fp.close()
    return reseau

def trouver_nombre_elements_communs_entre_listes(liste1, liste2):
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring"""
    compteur_amis_commun = 0
    for element in liste1:
        if element in liste2:
            compteur_amis_commun = compteur_amis_commun + 1
    return compteur_amis_commun


def initialiser_matrice(n):
    """
    Crée une matrice nxn, initialisée avec des zéros et retourne la matrice.
    Args:
        n (int): dimension de la matrice nxn
    Returns:
        matrice (list): matrice initialisée

    """
    matrice = []
    for ligne in range(n):  # pour chacune des lignes dans n
        matrice.append([])  # créer une ligne (liste) et l'initialiser à 0
        for colonne in range(n):
            matrice[ligne].append(0)  # ajouter un 0 pour chaque n colonne
    return matrice


def calculer_scores_similarite(reseau):
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring"""
    n = len(reseau)
    matrice_similarite = initialiser_matrice(n)
    liste1 = []
    liste2 = []
    compteur_liste1 = 0
    compteur_liste2 = 0

    for element_liste1 in reseau:
        liste1 = element_liste1
        for element_liste2 in reseau:
            liste2 = element_liste2
            compteur_amis_commun = trouver_nombre_elements_communs_entre_listes(liste1, liste2)
            matrice_similarite[compteur_liste1][compteur_liste2] = compteur_amis_commun
            compteur_liste2 = compteur_liste2 + 1
        compteur_liste1 = compteur_liste1 + 1
        compteur_liste2 = 0

    return matrice_similarite


def recommander(id_usager,reseau,matrice_similarite):
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring"""

    usager_matrice = matrice_similarite.index(id_usager)
    ami_recommande = matrice_similarite.index(max(usager_matrice))
    max_value = max(matrice_similarite.index(usager_matrice))

    if ami_recommande == id_usager:
        max_value = max_value - 1

    ami_recommande = matrice_similarite.index(max_value)

    while True:
        if ami_recommande == reseau.index(ami_recommande):
            ami_recommande = reseau.index(max_value, ami_recommande + 1)
            return True

    return ami_recommande

def main():

    nomFichier = input("Nom du fichier contenant le réseau: ")
    reseau = lire_fichier(ouvrir_fichier(nomFichier))
    n = len(reseau)
    matrice_similarite = calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)
    while True:

        while True:

            id_usager = int(input("Entrer l'ID de l'usager pour lequel vous voulez une recommandation (entre 0 et {}):".format(n)))
            if 0 <= id_usager and id_usager < n:
                calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)
                print("Pour la personne" , id_usager , ", nous recommandons l'ami" , recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite))
                continue
            else:
                print("Erreur: l'usager doit être un nombre entier entre ", 0, "et", n - 1, "inclusivement.\n")

        autreRecommandation = input("Voulez-vous une autre recommandation (oui/non)?")
        if autreRecommandation.lower() == "oui":
            return True
        else:
            print("Merci d'avoir utiliser le programme de recommandation d'amis.")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Most of the content seems to be working fine until I get to part where I need to recommend a user identification. I'll try to work on the doc string as well in the meantime but I could totally use a little bit of help as to debug this. I tested most of the code on another .py project until I hit the function `recommander`

First Edit:

I did forget to apply the `return`. I changed it and it is now in the `def`. Now however...I seem to be having this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1668, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 132, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 119, in main
    print("Pour la personne" , id_usager , ", nous recommandons l'ami" , recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite))
  File "C:/Users/101136/PycharmProjects/tp2/TP2.py", line 89, in recommander
    usager_matrice = matrice_similarite.index(id_usager)
ValueError: 0 is not in list
```

Also I'm wondering about a little something. The part where I ask for an input to define id_usager in the `def main()`, I was wondering if there was a way to also treat characters as well as integers. Integers, I got it covered with my code but if somebody wants to write boy instead of a number, it'll fail.

Comment: That's a whole lot of code and a very thin definition of the problem.

Comment: Yet the whole error log is present.

Comment: You're going to need to explain what this is all about.

Comment: I'm basically taking a list with 10 users. For now at least.
That being said, every data within it is considered as a list and I'm making a program to basically make a friend suggestion application.
I ask an input for the file name (currently, there are only two files) then ask for a user ID which for the first file is between 0 and 9 (10 users) and 0 and 999 for the second file (1000 users). That in mind, I give to the given user ID the user that has the most friends in common that's not itself or listed in its friends already.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a **[mcve]**. Keep word in this situation is *Minimal*.

Comment: le "id_usager" is equal to zero, which means matrice_similarite`s index equal to zero `s element is not there,empty list,matrice_similarite is not getting constructed properly, try to add print statetment for all variables you are passing to functions inside the function definition, you will get an idea where its failing ,bonne chance

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan In fact, it seems to be bugging at     usager_matrice = matrice_similarite.index(id_usager). id_usager being = to 0 is fine considering the index of a list can be 0 or is my understanding wrong?

I also changed the value of id_usager by putting 1 for instance, and I get the same error. This time, ValueError: 1 is not in list

Comment: @Nore, its not the case, before returning matrice_similarite, print its lenght.. it seems it empty,yes,a list index can be zero, that error you are getting, is when you access index 0 and there is no element in the list,before 'return matrice_similarite' put 'print(matrice_similarite)' for this you will be sure that your matrice_similarite is not empty

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan I did that and it returns this list which is perfectly fine to what it should be.[[3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3], [0, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0], etc. Not putting the whole list because it'd be too long. But the elements are present in the list when I do print(matrice_similarite)

Comment: i see where the problem is...matrice_similarite.index(user_id) ..

Comment: Right when I'm at usager_matrice = matrice_similarite.index(id_usager) is where I get the error.

Comment: this List.index(obj) is passed an element that is part of the list.. not the index itself. for example  liste_a=[1,2,3,"name"] ,. liste_a.index("name") returns 3, what you are trying to do should be achieved directry like matrice_similarite[id_user]

Comment: list.index(element) ,returns the index of that element in the list, if the 'elment' is not there, it throw an error that element is not in the list

Comment: bref...it does the opposite of what you are trying to do... give it directly like matrice_similarite[id_usager] it will returns the a list of similarity score vecteur at index of [id_usager]

Comment: That totally worked. Which means the following which I've done for ami_recommande and max_value doesn't work. I did test them and it doesn't work. Seems like I got the syntax wrong. I just looked it up online and tried something new but still no go.

Comment: Just reverse the synthax in am_recommande,in mean Time, can I add my answer for approval for the question that was asked?

Comment: Yes. Because that worked wonderfully.

Comment: Besides what do you mean reverse the syntax? I should do max(usager_matrice = ami_recommande ?

Comment: i added the answer, what i mean by reverse the synthax was instead of using matrice_similarite.index(id_usager) ,just use matrice_similarite[id_usager] and do the same to anywhere in the code you want to get an element of a list at index id_usager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accessing element of list is done by `list_name[index],` `list_name.index(element)` returns the index of that element,if they are two in the list it returns the index of the first one, if the element is not there,it throws a `ValueError`: "element" is not in the list.
in your case
change

```
 usager_matrice = matrice_similarite.index(id_usager)
```

to

usager_matrice =matrice_similarite[id_usager]

and other places you want to access element of a list using index

in the scond question from the comment, check if its numeric like this

```
id_usager =input("Entrer l'ID de l'usager pour lequel vous voulez une recommandation (entre 0 et {}):".format(n))

if not id_usager.isdigit():
   continue
id_user=int(id_usager)
```

note that this will convert also floats into int

Comment: Besides, on another note which I originally added in the question. Would you know how to make it so that when I get an input from a user, albeit being text it treats it as a mistake instead of crashing the program? I managed to do it just fine with integers. Can't do it with the str if there would be a str instead of an int. Line is towards the end with the error message in the while.